# Call rest API to upload file with form data using cUrl PHP

Tags: php, api, file, curl

I have an API to upload file

in Postman it is working fine (see link http://prntscr.com/oirpnb)
so ho can I implement in my PHP code?

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost/test/api/api/retailer/shop/update/image",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"shopId\"\r\n\r\n50\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"apple-brunette-diet-41543.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: */*",
    "Authorization: cU5GMlkzWjFkZ3lFemRiMXdTVDk1Mk5JM2tzMHhtckxvMk9mOUdVN1VLbkZFYWZMTGN1b1l0cXJPcVBO5d369cdab2d74",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Host: localhost",
    "Postman-Token: e35c2fc5-6b2a-4047-964e-a97a8ea51e28,0403395b-eae3-4971-94b5-e756657ad932",
    "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.0",
    "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-length: 91755",
    "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Now, how can i use this in my PHP code?

Comment: Isn't the code above is PHP already? does it work?

Comment: This code is given by postman
http://prntscr.com/oirsiy

Comment: How to perform an image upload using cURL in PHP is something you should really be able to easily research yourself. This does not look like you made an actual effort so far.

Comment: i have already a REST api to upload file.
So, i just need to call that api and need to pass 
shopId=50
image=input file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$file = $request->file('image');
$filePath = $file->getPathName();
$type = 'image/jpeg';
$fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();

$data = array(
    'shopId' => 50,
    'image' => curl_file_create($filePath, $type, $fileName)
);

$apiEndPoint='http://localhost/test/api/api/retailer/shop/update/image';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiEndPoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: What do you want to tell us with that answer? Does it solve the problem? Or is this additional code - then please add it to the question by editing it